# \includeonly stops the composition

Tags: chapters

From the installation of texlive2021 it is impossible to use `\includeonly` to compose the different chapters of a book one at a time: with `\includeonly{***}`, the composition stops immediately! Is it a conséquence of `hyperref`? How can I correct that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,color,12pt]{nj23} \def\titrejournal{Ratiocinations} 
\def\titrejcourt{Ratiocinations} 
\def\numero{7} \def\millesime{2021} \def\mois{Septembre} \def\incniv#1{\incgr[width=0.75cm]{Frac.jpg}\space} \definecolor{coul}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,0.1} \def\coulbas{coul} \includeonly{TDM} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\include{TeXLive} 
\include{TDM} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ....

Comment: latex never stops without warning, show the full error message from the log also show your input, `\includeonly` works in general, it is hard to say what is wrong with your file if you do not show it.

Comment: I am sorry: I get absolutely no "full error message". Here is the main page of my project.  \documentclass[a4paper,color,12pt]{nj23}
\def\titrejournal{Ratiocinations}
\def\titrejcourt{Ratiocinations}
\def\numero{7}
\def\millesime{2021}
\def\mois{Septembre}
\def\incniv#1{\incgr[width=0.75cm]{Frac.jpg}\space}
\definecolor{coul}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,0.1}
\def\coulbas{coul}
\includeonly{TDM}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\include{TeXLive}
\include{TDM}
\end{document}
nj23 is a class I dérive from book in order to public a magazine.

Comment: Obviously we don't have your custom `nj23` class, but if I use `book` instead, `\includeonly` works just fine. I do get a couple of other errors though, which has to be fixed first: one from `\definecolor` (which needs `\usepackage{xcolor}` -- you may have that in the class?) and one from using `\maketitle` without having `\author{}` and `\title{}`. Adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` doesn't break anything. In other words, you'll probably have to provide more info.